# Bootstrap several angular applications using platform-browser

Tags: angular

I'm trying to run 3-4 angular applications on the page. Initially, all of them have been using platformBrowserDynamic and JIT compiler. I started to migrate one of the applications to platformBrowser and AOT compiler. Given that, I didn't manage to run AOT application because angular throws the next error:

```
Uncaught Error: There can be only one platform. Destroy the previous one to create a new one.
```

The code which throws the error I found here https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts#L87

Used Angular 4.0.1 and framework is included only once on a page.

Regarding all above I have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible somehow to start several different angular applications on different platforms on the same page?
2. Is it possible to start different applications using platformBrowser on the same page?